# Python socket send message Invalid HTTP

Tags: python, django, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have at my django project a socket server [django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio)
(that works normally), and i try to send message message for it by using the following code:

```
import socket
import json

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect(('127.0.0.1' , 9000))
data = {
    'username': 'avt',
    'password': 123,
    'amount': 100
}
message = json.dumps(data)
s.sendall(message)
```

And receive error:

```
<socket fileno=5 sock=127.0.0.1:9000 peer=127.0.0.1:58952>: Invalid HTTP method: '{"username": "avt", "amount": 100, "password": 123}'
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're sending raw data through a socket connected to a server expecting a valid HTTP request. Or am I missed something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking to a WebSocket server. Therefore you need to use the [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) protocol.

Your code sends the following string to the server:

```
{"username": "avt", "amount": 100, "password": 123}
```

but you actually need to send something like this (which begins the protocol handshake):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 127.0.0.1:9000
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:9000
Sec-WebSocket-Key: gCJZxvFvQ2Wa/flhLUvAtA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

The above request was generated using [websocket-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client) with this code:

```
import json
import websocket

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:9000/')
ws.close()
```

You can experiment with a WebSocket echo server:

```
ws.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org/')
# now you can send data...
data = {
    'username': 'avt',
    'password': 123,
    'amount': 100
}

>>> ws.send(json.dumps(data))
57
>>> ws.recv()
'{"username": "avt", "amount": 100, "password": 123}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your django app expects valid HTTP requests (as described here : http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html), not a mere json dump. So you either need to manually write a (correct) full blown HTTP request, or use some higher level tool like the stdlib's `urllib` or, even better, the third-part "requests" lib (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).